Any Chess Players with ADHD?
I'm trying to conduct a study to analyze if people with different cognitive conditions have different play styles, make the same mistakes, etc.
I was curious if there were any chess players who are diagnosed with ADHD or ADD, and what your experience is playing with this condition. Do you notice different play styles than your opponents? preference to blitz, rapid, or classical? etc.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=340A40L9PgA
